# How to unitTest CakePHP 3.x Controller Actions that require HTTP Basic Authentication?

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, basic-authentication, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.2

I'am trying to authenticate a user by adding the `PHP_AUTH_USER` and `PHP_AUTH_PW` to the `$_ENV`-Variable, but this has no affect. I'am using the following configuration with `memory`-Storage:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Basic' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password'],
                'userModel' => 'CmUsers'
            ],
        ],
        'storage' => 'Memory',
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => false
]);
```

The Test fails with `exception 'Cake\Network\Exception\UnauthorizedException' with message 'Unauthorized'`.

```
public function testIndex()
{         
    $_ENV['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = 'ApiUser';  
    $_ENV['PHP_AUTH_PW'] = '123456';   

    $this->get('/index');                

    $this->assertResponseOk();                         
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to add the authentication-data to the request?

If I follow the advice from @ndm and add the `Authentication`-Header...

```
$this->configRequest([
            'environment' => [
                'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'ApiUser',
                'PHP_AUTH_PW' => '123456',                  
            ],
            'headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Basic ApiUser:123456']
]);
```

... the envirement Variables looks like this:

```
[_environment:protected] => Array
    (
        [HTTP_AUTHORIZATION] => Basic ApiUser:123456
        [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
        [PHP_AUTH_USER] => ApiUser
        [PHP_AUTH_PW] => 123456
        [HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE] => 
        [ORIGINAL_REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
        [SERVER_PORT] => 
        [HTTPS] => 
        [HTTP_HOST] => 
    )
```

My Fixture looks like this:

```
public $records = [
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'username' => 'ApiUser',
        'password' => '123456',
        'role' => 'api-user',
        'created' => 1460710056,
        'modified' => 1460710056
    ],        
];
```

Unfortunately the request still gets blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integration test cases should never fiddle with superglobals, as they usually aren't touched by the test case in order to avoid polluting the test environment with non-CakePHP request related data.

The test request can be configured via the `\Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase::configRequest()` method. It accepts an array which will basically just be passed to the `\Cake\Network\Request` constructor of the request object used by the test.

Long story short, environment variables can be defined via the `environment` config key, like

```php
public function testIndex()
{
    $this->configRequest([
        'environment' => [
            'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'ApiUser',
            'PHP_AUTH_PW' => '123456'
        ]
    ]);  

    $this->get('/index');                

    $this->assertResponseOk();                         
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Testing > Setting up the Request](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#setting-up-the-request)**
- **[API > \Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase::configRequest()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.TestSuite.IntegrationTestCase.html#_configRequest)**
- **[API > \Cake\Network\Request::__construct()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Network.Request.html#___construct)**

Comment: Thanks, thats a good advice. Unfortunately the request still gets blocked. I' am wondering if I have to write the Userdata somehow manually in the Memory-Database?! In my development envirement it works fine, but in my testcases is fails.

Comment: Even adding the header `'headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Basic ApiUser:123456']` to the `configRequest` does not work.

Comment: @Niklas Works fine for me, looking at your updated question, your fixture is incorrect, as the password isn't hashed! The fixture data will be written directly to the database (via `Query::insert/into()`), it is not being processed by your tables and entities, ie the password will be stored as is.